# To attach a ButtonField on every row of CustomListField in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to create a **ObjectListField** with one image ,some text and a **ButtonField** with each row. Its ok with image and text in a row, but I want to create one button at the end of every row which independently performs action related to that particular row.

Here, I have two different functionality on click , one is on clicking the row and another on clicking the button.So,how I can create such an ObjectListField?

Comment: No, and it is kind of bad design (you are probably thinking in touchscreens terms, but in legacy BB OS some devices don't have a touch screen, and trackpad and focus is used instead). If you need a button inside a row, then you need to get rid of ObjectListField and use a list made with managers.